# Python Plotting DateTime Format

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, plot

I am working with a twitter data and I want to plot it to display how many tweet occurs in a day. I used `groupby` function to count how many tweet occurs. The `date` data type is already converted to datetime. It looks roughly like this.

```
date                  tweet
2020-07-25 12:27:21   2
2020-02-13 10:04:16   4
```

I tried this code but got a `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(df['date'], df['tweet'])
```

What is the best way to do this? And also since I only need the day, month and year format, will the hour, minute and second need to be removed? If so, please include it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this should help you!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-07-25 12:27:21', 2], ['2020-02-13 10:04:16', 4]], columns = ['Date', 'Tweet'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : ' ' if x=="NaT" else x)

cou = df['Tweet'].values
dat = df['Date'].values

plt.bar(dat, cou)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

[image]